# UWP: Int parameter fails on RelayCommand

Tags: c#, uwp, relaycommand, uno

This code with string parameter work:

```
public RelayCommand<string> myCommand { get; private set; }
myCommand = new RelayCommand<string>((s) => Test(s));

private void Test(string s)
{
    //DoSomething();
}
```

This code with int parameter does not work and gives [Compiler Error CS0452](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0452?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0452)):

```
public RelayCommand<int> myCommand { get; private set; }
myCommand = new RelayCommand<int>((s) => Test(s));

private void Test(int s)
{
    //DoSomething();
}
```

RelayCommand Class to bind with command on xaml UI:

```
    public class RelayCommand<TParameter> : System.Windows.Input.ICommand
where TParameter : class
{
    protected readonly System.Func<TParameter, bool> _canExecute;
    private readonly System.Action<TParameter> _execute;
    public RelayCommand(System.Action<TParameter> execute)
    : this(execute, null)
    {
    }
    public RelayCommand(System.Action<TParameter> execute, System.Func<TParameter, bool> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
        { 
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        }
            
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter as TParameter);
    }
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter as TParameter);
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        System.EventHandler handler = CanExecuteChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, System.EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas other than convert it to object type?

Comment: Are you using UNO? What's is the RelayCommand Class? If it is a class you defined, could you please share the code about RelayCommand?

Comment: Added RelayCommand Class, yes i'm using Uno Plataform for droid, ios and uwp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to use your `RelayCommand<TParameter>` implementation with a value type such as `int`, you need to remove the type constraint and the use of the `as` operator:

```
public class RelayCommand<TParameter> : System.Windows.Input.ICommand
{
    protected readonly System.Func<TParameter, bool> _canExecute;
    private readonly System.Action<TParameter> _execute;
    public RelayCommand(System.Action<TParameter> execute)
    : this(execute, null)
    {
    }
    public RelayCommand(System.Action<TParameter> execute, System.Func<TParameter, bool> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        }

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_canExecute == null)
            return true;

        if (parameter is TParameter)
            return _canExecute((TParameter)parameter);

        return false;
    }
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (parameter is TParameter)
            _execute((TParameter)parameter);
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        System.EventHandler handler = CanExecuteChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, System.EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```